# Why my car "sweats"?

Tags: alfa-romeo, cold-weather

pretty new here, so if it is a newbie question please forgive me.

I have a 2007 AlfaGT in pretty good conditions, now that here in Italy the weather became very cold , I realized that my car kinda "sweats" (i literally find some water drops in certain point like the glasses or the handle car) in certain point, so the ice and sleet on the car is pretty huge compared to others.

Note that i had prevoius cars, so i know is perfectly normal to wake up and find the car pretty cold , but with this one the fact is different .

EDIT: the car overly "sweats" outside
EDIT2: [image: here you can see an image of the car , note that other cars are just cold, with no ice or sleet]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Is the "sweating" on the inside or outside of the car?

Comment: from memory the parts you are talking about are metal and therefore colder than most other cars equivalents made of plastic, they will attract water vapour as dew and then it freezes.

Comment: @Mauro - That definitely sounds reasonable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the picture you have provided, it appears you are seeing condensation deposited on the car. When water vapor in the warm air, meets with a cold surface, water droplets form through the natural process of condensation. This happens more readily in humid climates.

It is likely the finish, or color, of your car makes it more noticeable. Look closely at other cars, I bet you will see it on them also.